# Tx_news "502-Bad Gateway" in backend

Tags: nginx, typo3, tx-news

I'm using Nginx and the extension tx_news. When I'm working in backend with news(cut,edit,close,...) I get sometimes a 502-Bad Gateway exception. This exception I get after a second. I don't understand what's going wrong here. Sometimes it works well and sometimes I get this exception more often. I only get this exception in combination with tx_news. The rest of backend is working fine. Maybe this is only a configuration problem of nginx connections or something like this. Is anybody here who has an idea?

Every hint can help me :-)!

Answer (score 0):

Check the consistency of your database records on such a page.

I used to get 502 bad gateway errors on Nginx after copying a page with fluidcontent elements because somhow a FCE got itself as its parent, which caused an infinite loop upon rendering the page module. But all I saw was the bad gateway page. This only happened with a specific version of fluidcontent.

Maybe you have some relations in your news records that are circular after pasting? Worth checking for it.